# Going back one iteration in a complicated for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to python and to my understanding of for loops is that they do not work the same way as they do in C which means you cannot go back one iteration by subtracting 1 from your range variable. But is there an easy implementation to still go back on iteration?

The for loop is defined as:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
```

I want that if a certain event occurs I can go back and recheck the current folder and all the files/folders in it. And then continue onwards.

- The code basis isn't written by me (I'm only adding functionality)
- the amount of folders and files in "path" is unknown and can change drastically
- the for loop itself is 200 lines long and calls functions worth another 500 lines. (so rewriting the whole logic would be hard)

*Please give constructive criticism to improve the question.*

Comment: How does the event look like? Is it a simple check, is it dependent on what's going on inside the loop?

Comment: Move the entire body of the loop into a function then add your condition to the loop and remember the prior value for root in the last loop iteration and then if the condition matches have another loop start at that root and call the loop body. Or something like that but it is hard to say more without seeing the loop.

Comment: You can save all folders in a list, and if you need get previous list element

Comment: @IuliusCurt The function does look for wrong file/folder names, an event would be a wrong name.
The event gets detected because a variable is set to != 0

Comment: Why not do a conditioned inner loop in the same fashion, starting from the path you need?

Comment: @Alderven but "knowing" the previous list element doesn't enable me to rerun the for loop with this element without starting a whole new for loop

Comment: @GittingGud, so when `/level1/level2/file` is wrong, you want to redo all the files inside `level2`?

Comment: @IuliusCurt if the functions inside the for loop detect a folder1 with wrongly named files2/folders2 in it there is the possibility for the user to fix those. After the user input the functions inside the for loop should recheck all the files2/folders2 in folder1

Comment: @GittingGud Feel free to accept one of the answers if it worked as a solution for you, or post a short self-answer if you found another solution

Comment: @IuliusCurt  I got an additional task with a higher priority so I wasn't able to continue this line of work. I will continue my work on this topic probably in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the values from precedent step (i.e. n-1) you can simply assign them to some variables (prevRoot, prevDirs, prevFiles) and rewrite them after. From what you wrote I assume you do not require storing all previous results in a list.

If that is the case, you can try this:

```
import os

dir = 'c:\\'

for n, (root, dirs, files) in enumerate(os.walk(dir)):

    if n == 0:
        prevRoot = root
        prevDirs = dirs
        prevFiles = files

    print n
    print (root, dirs, files)
    print (prevRoot, prevDirs, prevFiles)
    #DO YOUR STUFF HERE

    if n > 0:
        prevRoot = root
        prevDirs = dirs
        prevFiles = files
```

Answer (score 1):

Store path walking result in a list:

```py
walk_list=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    walk_list.append((root,dirs,files))
```

Then write your own loop iterating the walk_list **with an index number**, once you want to go back, subtract the index number.

Answer (score 1):

Using an inner loop in the case that the condition is triggered. This inner loop would redo all the siblings of the triggering file that were already processed and then go back to usual checking.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if triggered:
        parent = os.path.dirname(root)
        # Recheck all files and folders already checked before
        # bumping into the current file
        for redo_root, redo_dirs, redo_files in os.walk(parent):
            if redo_root == root:
                break  # "And then continue onwards"
            DO_STUFF(redo_root, redo_dirs, redo_files)
    DO_STUFF(root, dirs, files)
```